# Change WordPress wp_nav_menu link classes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to figure out, how I can add a class to the wp_nav_menu links `<a>`. I can always found question and tutorials how I can change the `<li>` or `<ul>` class of the generator, but nothing about the link `<a>` classes.

This is my little piece of code:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="add-class-here" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to add a class to the `<a>` (link) element. How the hack can I do this?

Comment: You have the code right there! This is exactly how you would do this. If you want custom classes with a dynamic wordpress menu: [read this](https://www.lockedownseo.com/add-css-classes-to-menu-items-in-wordpress/). This is how you would manually add classes to wordpress menu items. Instead of selecting `.add-class-here` you would have to select `.add-class-here a`, since the article I sent adds a class to the `<li>` element

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. Maybe I was a bit to fast asking a new one:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'nav_menu_link_class', 10, 3 );
function nav_menu_link_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $class         = 'has-ripple';
    $atts['class'] = $class;

    return $atts;
}
```

So this is how I've added a ripple class to all of my link object. Looks cool now!

Comment: Ah that's what you meant! Good

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman So it's working but it also add this to the main menu. I only need it in the sub-menu. But I'll do this with css I think.

Comment: You can always copy [the `wp_nav_menu()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). On the same website you can also read how you can achieve this. https://developer.wordpress.org/